# Create Button Under Actions To Redirect To Report In Acumatica CA304000

Tags: acumatica, erp

I am trying to add an option under Actions in Acumatica on the Transactions screen CA304000. See below what I am trying to achieve:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using PX.Data;
 using PX.Objects.Common;
 using PX.Objects.AP;
 using PX.Objects.CM;
 using PX.Objects.CS;
 using PX.Objects.GL;
 using PX.Objects.IN;
 using PX.Objects.TX;
 using PX.Objects.EP;
 using PX.Objects.CR;
 using Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter;
 using Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter.TaxService;
using AvaAddress = Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter.AddressService;
using AvaMessage = Avalara.AvaTax.Adapter.Message;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.CA;

namespace PX.Objects.CA
{

    public class CATranEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<CATranEntry>
            {

#region Event Handlers
               public override void Initialize()
               {
                   Base.action.AddMenuAction(ShowURL);
               }

  public PXAction<CAAdj> ShowURL; 
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Phieu Thu")] 
  [PXButton]

  protected virtual void showURL() 
  { 
     CAAdj doc = Base.Document.Current;
     if (doc.RefNbr != null)
     {
         throw new PXReportRequiredException(doc, "TNCA6401", null);
     }

    }


    #endregion

    }
}
```

This is however telling me that there is ('PX.Objects.CA.CATranEntry' does not contain a definition for 'Document' and no extension method 'Document' accepting a first argument of type 'PX.Objects.CA.CATranEntry' could be found) twice.

this  TNCA6401 only have one paramenter Reference Number. Please be specific (Image is the best). I'm Noob. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be working with `CAAdjRecords` data view not `Document`. 
`CAAdj doc = Base.Document.Current;` 
should be `CAAdj doc = Base.CAAdjRecords.Current`

And `Reference Nbr.` is tied to `AdjRefNbr` field.

You could use `Customization -> Inspect Element` to identify screen is working with which `Graph`, `Data View`, `DAC` and `DAC field`.

[image]